# MS SQL Server field with Data type of Money shows empty field in MS ACCESS linked table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am migrating a MS Access back end data file to SQL Server.  All data has successfully transferred, and it viewable in SSMS, however, if I open the linked table in the Access front end, all currency field entries that are greater than 0 are blank.

If I run a query that filters currency columns based on their value, I get the correct number of records returned, but still the fields show as blank.

This makes no sense to me, please help.

Comment: I've tested this by creating a new table in SQL with a money column (not displayed in Access), then Altering the column to decimal, and it then shows in the Access query. Although this is a potential work-around, I'd rather know why this was happening and have a genuine solution, so I don't make these kinds of changes only to find they are also susceptible to the same issue.

Comment: I've never seen this. It sounds like a formatting issue.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, but the SQL table field is a money field with no custom formatting (not sure how this is done anyway) and the table is directly linked to with Access, so no formatting is permitted because it is a linked table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try linking the table using sql driver (this is a long time legacy driver). It been pre-installed on computers since windows XP.

If that does not work, then try linking using the native 11 (or later driver). These drivers are preferred, but they are not installed on each workstation and thus deployment can be a hassle.

And to prevent the need to configure each workstation? Always (but always) use a FILE dsn. This is suggested because Access will convert the connection automatic to DSN-less. This means that you not  have to setup a DSN on each workstation (but you STILL require the native driver 11-17 having been  installed on each workstation, and that driver will have to match what you linked with.

If EITHER of the above STILL does not display the money type columns?
Then this is a regional setting. (the regional setting of the sql server is not matching what your regional settings are on the client workstation.

So, then create a new DSN (as noted always FILE).
And during the re-link process try selecting the regional settings:

[image]

So, you should not have to change the "money" type to decimal. And doing so could introduce all kinds of issues.
So, try the above first. Both the legacy (windows built in) "sql driver", and the natve 11-17 drivers work for me WITHOUT having to select the above regional settings, but if both sql legacy and the newer native 11 (or later) drivers don't work, then try re-linking again and selecting the above option.

NOTE ALSO that you do NOT get the above panel during a re-link, nor do you get the above panel during a re-fresh. Nor do you get the above panel if  you select a existing DSN. You MUST create a new DSN to get/see/use the above panel. It ONLY appears one time, and ONLY during the time you create a new DSN - not during re-use or a re-link or a re-select of a existing DSN.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in confirming this. What wished for me was leaving the regional settings checkbox unticked. Ticking it (with I must have done) resulted in my problems.

Comment: Great. It REALLY helps others to you to come back and share this issue. So, a miss match in client and server sql reginal settings looks to be the issue. Interesting that I was suggesting to check the box - you come back and found that NOT checking the box fixes this. Either way, EVERYONE here will be helped by you confirming to look at, and be aware of the regional settings issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this takes me back.

Assuming you're using an ODBC DSN to set the connection for the linked tables, set the ODBC data source to use the "SQL Server Native Client" driver, not the "SQL Server" driver. As I recall you can't change the driver for a DSN, so you'll have to remove your existing one and create a new one.

To get there:

Open start menu > type "odbc data sources" > click to open odbc data sources > click add > scroll all the way to the bottom of the drivers list and choose SQL Server Native Client as the driver > set up the rest of the DSN according to your environment.